# Correlations - Pearson and Spearman

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho

I know that Pearson correlation is sensitive to outliers, unlike Spearman correlation.  I am trying to generate data (let's say with at least 30 points) that will maximize the difference between these two methods. I was trying to generate some points in an ascending linear direction, and then one outlier point in the opposite direction. It indeed showed a big difference in the coefficients, but not as much as I wanted. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe something that maximizes the difference between a linear trend and a monotonic trend ?  Perhaps, in R, `x = 0:10 + 0.000000001; y = 1/x; plot(x,y); cor(x,y, method="pearson"); cor(x,y, method="kendall")` . This can be run at: [rdrr.io/snippets/](https://rdrr.io/snippets/) .  Or change that decimal to e.g. 0.3 to make the plot more obvious.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried that but both methods return values of the same sign. I try to make opposite signs, when at least one value is significant

Comment: Your idea is fine.

Answer (score 16):

**Pearson correlation depends on the values of the data; Spearman correlation depends only on their (marginal) ranks.  Thus, the former is (far) more sensitive to outlying data.**

What kind of outlying data?  Those with high *leverage.*  These are far to the left or right of the rest of the points in a plot, as in the left panel in the figure.
[image: Figure]

**That isolated point at $(20,20)$ pulls the least-squares line close to it** (for otherwise the squared penalty would be huge).  As a result, the Pearson correlation (which is the standardized slope of this line) must be large and *negative*.

However, that same point no longer has the same leverage in a plot of the *ranks* of the data: yes, it is off to the left again, but it cannot be far to the left.  It pulls the least squares line up only a little.  The Spearman correlation is large and positive, because the $30$ points already have high positive Spearman correlation and altering the value of one point cannot change those ranks all that much.

Flip these pictures upside-down for an example of a switch from a large *positive* Pearson correlation to a large *negative* Spearman correlation.

Fixing the rightmost 30 points along a line segment from $(-1,-1)$ to $(1,1),$ we may vary that outlying point $(a,-a)$ and plot the correlations as a function of $a.$

[image: Figure]

**The black curve tracks the Pearson correlation.**  When $a=0,$ the point $(0,0)$ fits in perfectly with the other $30$ points and the both correlations are $1.$  But for extremely negative and positive values of $a,$ this leverage phenomenon occurs and the two correlation coefficients separate.

**The dotted red curve tracks the Spearman correlation,** which stays high no matter what value $a$ might have.

In the limit, the Pearson correlation can approach $-1.$  The Spearman correlation reaches a lower limiting value that depends only on the amount of data: in the figure, it's about $0.806.$  With sufficiently large datasets, the Spearman correlation will stay very close to $1.$  For instance, repeating this example with $300+1$ points rather than $30+1$ points, the Spearman coefficient is never less than $0.980.$

**The gray (Pearson) and dotted blue (Spearman) curves show the situation with the $y$ values negated.**

> Thus, by making $n$ sufficiently large and pulling just a *single* point away from a highly correlated dataset, you can make the two correlation coefficients as close to $\pm 1$ as you want, but with opposite signs.

Answer (score 7):

> I know that Pearson correlation is sensitive to outliers, unlike Spearman correlation.

There is a more striking difference between the two: Pearson assumes a *linear* relationship between the data, whereas Spearman checks whether it is simply monotonuous (see the image below, taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)). Generating data via a non-linear process is thus a way to show that these are not equivalent.

> A Spearman correlation of 1 results when the two variables being compared are monotonically related, even if their relationship is not linear. This means that all data points with greater x values than that of a given data point will have greater y values as well. In contrast, this does not give a perfect Pearson correlation.
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic idea. In this example Spearman's correlation is obviously 1, and Pearson's correlation is 0.65. You can generate "step data" that will look like almost a straight line, then add an outlier.

[image: Person vs. Spearman]

Comment: This is somewhat similar to what suggested in the comment on the original question, which used *x*: 0 to 10 and *y* = 1 / *x*.  But you have to add a small number to *x*, to be able to calculate 1 / *x*.  Here I got *rho* = 1, and *r* = 0.5.